# Sort List<List<String>> by list value

Tags: java, list, sorting

I want sort the List by values in the list , it contains three values , first value is integer i convert that into string and other two values are string in nature, i want to sort the list by first string .

```
List<List<String>> detail_View = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

List<String> fieldValues =fieldValues = new ArrayList<String>();
String aString = Integer.toString(ScreenId);
fieldValues.add(aString);
fieldValues.add(DisplayScreenName);
fieldValues.add(TableDisplay);

detail_View.add(fieldValues);
```

In above code i have to sort list values by ScreenId

Comment: The below link has details with similar problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518359/using-collections-to-sort-values/19218759#19218759

Answer (score 4):

You have to use two concept:

1. `Collections.sort` utility.
2. `Comparator<T>` interface.

I write your solved problem following:

First you have to write your comparator:

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<List<String>>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<String> o1,
            List<String> o2)
        {
            String firstString_o1 = o1.get(0);
            String firstString_o2 = o2.get(0);
            return firstString_o1.compareTo(firstString_o2); 
        }
    }
```

then you using Collections utility as following:

```
Collections.sort(detail_View, new CustomComparator());
```

after these step, your list:

```
List<List<String>> detail_View = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

will sorted by first index of any nested list.

For more information related to this concept see:

1. http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html
2. http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-tips/data/collections_non_generic/comparators.shtml

Comment: You probably want to convert the String back to an integer first, though.

Comment: Yes, You can write complete custom code in your implementation of Comparator<T> interface.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that you do not want to sort the integer (stored as a String) alphabetically, you cannot use the default comparator, but have to convert it back to an integer first:

```
Collections.sort(detail_view, new Comparator<List<String>>(){
    int compareTo(List<String> a, List<String> b){
         return Integer.valueOf(a.get(0)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b.get(0));
    }
});
```

May I suggest not using a List for the three pieces of data, but your own bean class?

Answer (score 2):

Make a class with the three fields; don't move them around as a `List<String>`, that's just silly.  Making that class comparable will let you sort them as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 version:

```
Collections.sort(fieldValues, Comparator.comparing(e -> e.get(0)));
```

This version will sort the integers as numbers, not as strings:

```
Collections.sort(fieldValues, Comparator.comparing(e -> Integer.valueOf(e.get(0))));
```